# How can i change playlist title width in joomla's Jwplayer module?

Tags: joomla, jwplayer, playlist, joomla-module

When i setting jwplayer width not enough, the playerlist title can't fully display.

how can i change the title width?[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What Joomla plugin are you using?

You should simply make the player's width larger.

Comment: Thanks your answer!The joomla's module is jwplayer,but i can't make the width larger,it's depend on designer
Which file i can change it's css style?

Comment: I mean which module? We do not make a module for Joomla, so I was wondering where you downloaded it from?

Comment: Ah, this is not a module we have made. The only one we officially work with is - http://www.joomlarulez.com/